# How to call multiple OSGi modules

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have an OSGi project with three modules: Core, A and B. The idea is to launch/ run A and B whenever Core is launched.

Currently the approach I'm using just can't work in a real life application:

```
mvn clean install Core.jar
mvn clean install A.jar
mvn clean install B.jar
```

then

```
D:\felix-framework-5.4.0>java -jar bin\felix.jar

install file:/"D:/workingDir/Sample~1/Eclipse/Core-1.0.jar"
install file:/"D:/workingDir/Sample~1/Eclipse/A-1.0.jar"
install file:/"D:/workingDir/Sample~1/Eclipse/B-1.0.jar"
```

How can I achieve this. Are there any frameworks/ OSGi servers that I could use to implement this idea? What research topics could help in looking this up?

I would like to have Core in a root directory then other plugin bundles in a plugins folder. How can I dynamically look up and call the modules in the plugins folder from core?

```
OSGi-Project
    + Core.jar
    + plugins
        + A.jar
        + C.jar
        + D.jar
        + ****.jar
```

---

**UPDATE**

**Scenario**

The application I'm working on is an OSGi stand-alone desktop application. For example, Core would hold a pane on the left **(left-pane)**. left-pane will accept `nodes` from any module that implements an interface called `LeftPane`. **A** implements the `LeftPane` interface. Whenever Core is launched, it should scan through a folder, OSGi-Project in this case and automatically start all the bundles there, including A, which would go on to populate the left pane.

Comment: You are asking for a technical solution. I think it would be better to ask from a design level why you want to load the plugins and what they do in relation to core. I am pretty sure OSGi services can help you but I would need to know more about what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Christian Schneider. Thank you for the response. I have posted an update to the question which I think will help explain what I'm trying to accomplish. Please feel free to ask for any clarifications to the question on anything unclear. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification. As far as I can tell you do not really need dynamic loading or scanning. Instead I propose you let your plugin modules implement a service with interface LeftPane and publish it in the OSGi registry.

Your core module can then listen to all services that implement LeftPane and populate the UI from these.

To do this you can leverage the OSGi APIs around services or even better use a framework like DS or blueprint.

Answer (score 1):

http://inflamedjava.blogspot.co.at/2014/01/simple-plugin-management-using-osgi.html

You can't add a watcher on some other method. But what you could do, is to add some kind of an observer. If there is an action in core, you can get all available observers and trigger them.

```
Collection<ServiceReference<Observer>> refs = bundleContext.getServiceReferences(Observer.class);
for ( ... : refs ) {
   ref.invoke(...)
}
```